# unity crashed how to get it back on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Today i accidentally disabled the unity in compiz managier (ccsm),when the os struk i gave it a reboot,from then the unity is not see,how to start compiz and re enable unity